# MySQL 5.5.9: Can't figure out how to get my subquery to work properly

Tags: mysql

Basically what I am trying to do is.. I have a database setup with a row. The row has a primary key called "entry" and a value called "difficulty_entry_1". "difficulty_entry_1" refers to another entry as it's primary key, "entry". I am trying to select all of the data for the entry of "difficulty_entry_1"'s data without knowing the actual value in "difficulty_entry_1", but I do know the value in "entry"

```
Set @bossID = 26687

SELECT
        difficulty_entry_1 AS HbossID
        ,(select
            entry
            ,NAME
            ,healthmodifier
            ,damagemodifier
        FROM creature_template
        WHERE entry = HbossID;)
    FROM creature_template
    WHERE entry = @bossId;
```

Basically i want the outcome to be something like this

```
If     | Entry | Difficulty_entry_1 |
       |----------------------------|
       | 26687 |       12345        |


I want | Entry | Difficulty_entry_1 |
       |----------------------------|
       | 12345 |         0          |
```

without actually initially knowing the value in "difficulty_entry_1" but with initially knowing the value in table-1's "entry"

Hope this makes sense. New to actually posting on here. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it. For anyone having the same issue, this is the code i used to get the results i was looking for!

```
SET @bossID = 26687;
SELECT 
    entry
    ,NAME
    ,healthmodifier
    ,damagemodifier
FROM creature_template
WHERE entry = (SELECT difficulty_entry_1 FROM creature_template WHERE entry = @bossID);
```